# Why are detailed model processes and tools being shown in the progress window of Model Builder when it is double clicked / opened?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder

ArcGIS Desktop Advanced 10.1

The ESRI help notes state that when a model is run from"edit" in Model Builder all results are shown in the progress window - e.g. the progress of every tool and process.

The help notes also state that when the model tool is run from "open" or double clicked, only the overall progress of the model is shown in the progress window, not the progress of the individual tools or processes within the model.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Running_a_model_tool/002w0000004q000000/GUID-17578415-7F89-4BD4-BB9C-33B8F2220FEF/

This is the behavior I normally see for my Models.

However I have some models that when they are double clicked in ArcCatalog / or "open" when they run they show the full progress of every tool and process in the dialogue box.

Any ideas or experience of this behavior?

thanks for any tips / insight

Comment: Would you be able to use the edit button to included a graphic of one such model showing just the first few elements and also the corresponding output you see in the tool's result dialog, please?

Comment: OK, thanks yes i will add some images later on. My machine is locked up running models for the next few hours now though. The issue I am seeing is that the progress window shows the same full results progress as is it had been opened in edit and not via the open command!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake,

This issue is caused as follows

- when a model is password protected and it is run from the "open" menu or double clicked then the progress window does NOT show the full progress or each process being run
- when a model is not password protected then the results progress window is the same as in the edit window.

Almost all my models are password protected so i do not often see the results from the open window. the models that was causing this was one which was not password protected.

This is not particularly clear in the ESRI help notes.